# Center object and fix scaling

Tags: blender

I have imported my ZBrush model of some glasses into Blender.

For some reason, the glasses are not centered at all, and I'm having a hard time to navigate it.

I would like to center it so take I can easily navigate around it.
I think the glasses are also not correctly scaled, but I guess I should care about that later.

I have uploaded my model here:

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45773

Can anybody tell me how this should be done?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bottom menu: `Object` -> `Transform` -> `Origin to Geometry`
2. [`N`] menu: set all three location values to `0.0`
3. Profit

The first step makes sure the origin of your object lies in its geometric center. Currently, the origin is far, far below the glasses. The second step then simply moves your glasses to the center of the coordinate system.

Also, in the 'N' menu (hit 'N' to open it, will show up on the right hand side), you can set the scale just as easily as you have just set the location. Once you are happy with the scale, you might want to use `Apply` -> `Scale` (you can get that menu via `CTRL`+`A`) to make sure the new size will be used when exporting the model, for example.

Hope this helps. Oh, also: there is a dedicated [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you. Do you perhaps know if I can show a ruler in Blender in order to quickly scale my model?

Comment: Don't know about any ruler, but the grid in the background of the 3D view should give you an idea. Of course, this is in abstract "units", though you can set it to something more meaningful by going to the `Scene` menu (third icon-button in the right-hand side menu, it shows a sphere, cylinder and a sun of sorts) and changing the *Units* from `None` to `Metric`, for example. Then watch the text in the top-left corner of the 3d view.

Comment: When the scene is set to use metric units, I found the glasses to have a reasonable size (about 14 cm in width) when the scale is set to `0.04`.

Comment: Ah, also: the `N` menu shows the dimensions of your model (in abstract units or meters or centimeters or what-not, depending on the aforementioned scene settings).

Comment: @domdom The `N` menu shows the dimensions in Blender Units, which are equivalent to meters. You can edit the dimensions of the model in the `N` menu by clicking on them. To make the changes permanent, hit `Ctrl` + `A` > *Scale*.